# How to see Load Balancers traffic being distributed between my Subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I currently have 2 subnets which traffic is being routed to my Instances through, is there logs or log commands I can execute to display the traffic being routed correctly to make sure they all work fine without checking the web server page?

Comment: tcpdump (linux) or wireshark (windows) may be a good alternative to get traffic logs at EC2 instances

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no such metric or log. You would have to publish the logs or [custom metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) from the instances to CloudWatch yourself.

You could also probably setup [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to monitor incoming traffic to the instances and analyze the resulting logs.